# Getting JSON data from website returns " string(0) "

Tags: php, json

I;m trying to get data from a website using the following code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=4798';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($content);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

var_dump($json);

for ($idx = 0; $idx < count($json); $idx++) {
$obj = (Array)$json[$idx];
echo 'result' . $obj["name"];
}
?>
```

Which is getting me this result:

> string(0) "" NULL

Comment: What is the result of the var_dump($content) ? You can also use json_last_error() and json_last_error_msg() to debug issues decoding json.

Comment: $content is the data from the $url and returns String(0)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=4798';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($content);
$data = json_decode($content);
print_r($data);  //Show the json decoded data comes form $url 

##Parse this array {$data} using foreach loop as your use  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no numeric keys in the json returned from the url you posted in your question. So iterating through the associative array with numeric keys returns nothing.

This is the structure of the json you are working with:

```
{
  "item": {
    "icon": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/5122_obj_sprite.gif?id=4798",
    "icon_large": "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/5122_obj_big.gif?id=4798",
    "id": 4798,
    "type": "Default",
    "typeIcon": "http://www.runescape.com/img/categories/Default",
    "name": "Adamant brutal",
    "description": "Blunt adamantite arrow... ouch.",
    "current": {
      "trend": "neutral",
      "price": 529
    },
    "today": {
      "trend": "neutral",
      "price": 0
    },
    "members": "true",
    "day30": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-9.0%"
    },
    "day90": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-20.0%"
    },
    "day180": {
      "trend": "negative",
      "change": "-31.0%"
    }
  }
}
```

Try accessing `$json["item"]`. That should give you something more meaningful to work with. If you want to iterate over the key/value pairs in the item, use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($json["item"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ":";
    print_r($value);
}
```